# Unable to write extracted data from regular expression to excel file

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, beanshell

I am new to performance testing, I am trying to write extracted data from boundary extractor to an excel file using BeanShell scripting. The outcome is that my CSV file is getting updated but data is not showing in the file. instead of data is mentioned as "Null" in the CSV file

Extracted data from boundary extractor is :-Chris Evans,Robert Downey Jr.,Chris Hemsworth,Brie Larson,Josh Brolin,Scarlett Johansson,Benedict Wong,Paul Rudd,Mark Ruffalo,Karen Gillan,Jeremy Renner,Jon Favreau,Gwyneth Paltrow,Evangeline Lilly,Michelle Pfeiffer,Elizabeth Olsen,Chadwick Boseman,Sebastian Stan,Tom Holland,Pom Klementieff,Tilda Swinton,Benedict Cumberbatch,Katherine Langford,Dave Bautista,Letitia Wright,Frank Grillo,Tessa Thompson,Don Cheadle,Ty Simpkins,Terry Notary,Danai Gurira,Bradley Cooper

USed below code:

CastCrew = vars.get("CastCrew");

f = new FileOutputStream("C:\Users\Vikas Dhiman\Downloads\apache-jmeter-4.0\apache-jmeter-4.0\bin\examples\argList1.csv");

p = new PrintStream(f);

this.interpreter.setOut(p);

print("Cast and Crew are," + CastCrew);

f.close();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use two backslash in beanshell in directory path as shown below. I am sharing the config sample for your requirement:-

[image: Boundary Extractor]
[image: BeanShell Code]
[image: CSV output]

Hope this helps.